# file locking C programming

Tags: c, file, locks

Hello every one I am making a program using filing I know how to read an write in a file .But please can any one help me about the file read write locks in C programming.Like how to insert lock and how to  release it especially in forking .Please any give a small example or a tutorial as i didn't file any thing about file locks in c

Thanks

Comment: Typing your question title in google gives [this](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/flocking.html) as a first hit. There are many other relevant hits. Please post specific questions. (Also note that file locking is unfortunately not very portable.)

Answer (score 1):

File locking is not part of C, but is dependent on the operating system. Since you talk abour forking I assume you are using UNIX or a UNIX-like system (e.g. Linux or BSD.)

In that case you can use the `flock` or `lockf` functions. These locks are preserved on forking, which means that multiple processes can have an exclusive lock to the same file if the lock was acquired in the parent process before the fork.

On Windows it can be specified in the `CreateFile`call, or later with the `LockFile` or `LockFileEx` functions.